# Django: @property decorator on to emulate .queryset property

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view which has dynamic queryset. But to use `DjangoModelPermissions` I need `.queryset` attribute. So I tried to use `@property` decorator on `def queryset(self):` but it does not work. Below is a code snippet.

```
@property
def queryset(self):
    return self.module.none()
```

But `DjangoModelPermissions` still complains about `.queryset` not being available. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine. The `self.module` was not initialized and returned `none`.